# Trying to test whether element has attribute without directly assessing the element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to create query object on clicks on various buttons by sending attributes on html called "attr-{{foo}}" which get their name from an ng-repeat or some other means. I wanted on controller that first tests if the element has all attributes that map onto the keys of the query object in the scope, and continue this if else chain down to having only one attribute; however, when I tried this, I would get the error "cannot find .value of 'null'", as I was testing with

(below you will find a snippet that is representative of my controller)

```
 vm.openFoos = function (event) {
 if (event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-foo').value && 
  !event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-bar').value) {
  var obj = {
    foo: event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-foo').value,
    name: $routeParams.name
  } else if {
  (event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-foo').value && 
   event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-bar').value) {
  var obj = {
    foo: event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-foo').value,
    name: $routeParams.name,
    bar: event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-bar').value
   }
  }
  data.getReviews(obj)
    .success(function (data){$log.debug(data)}).error(function(e){$log.debug(e)}); 
};
```

This works if I click on elements with both attr-foo and attr-bar (as by the convention of this testing from most strict case of having attributes to least, I know if I had written the if statements in reverse I would get the error "cannot find value of null". Sample HTML:

```
<span class="one" ng-click="vm.openFoos($event) attr-foo="foooo">Click FOOO</span>

<span class="two" ng-click="vm.openFoos($event) attr-foo="fo" attr-bar="bar">Click FOO BAR</span>
```

Clicking span.one throws the error "cannot find value of null" but clicking span.two works fine.
I do not want to write a controller for each instance of the combinations of keys in my query appearing on various html attributes; however, I'm getting this error.

Comment: Syntax error: `else if {`. Also, the `else if` follows `var obj = ...`, which is another syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using

```
if (event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-thing').value ....
```

use

```
if (event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-thing') ....
```

When

```
event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('attr-thing')
```

does not exist, obviously one cannot take the value of it!

Answer (score 1):

Could you be looking for `hasOwnProperty`?

```
object.hasOwnProperty("attrname"); // Yields true or false.
```